# Depositing a check with a DBA on the title

Tags: united-states

If I have check made to me and on the next line it has a DBA name, can I deposit this item into a personal account? The check does not contain an "and".

Comment: This may vary by bank, but I would assume you can if your name is on it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's your business, endorse the check as yourself and your DBA name, payable to your personal account